# How to get rid of example value in swagger ui response

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am getting an example value in JSON when it should just be blank or not have an example at all since the result is a zipfile. I can't take a screen shot since its on another machine but its under

```
Responses

Code         Description
----------   ----------
200          OK
             
             (Example Value that I dont want)
```

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Download all files in a zip file.", response = Resource.class)
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}.zip)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFiles(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id
{
    Resource resource = service.loadFiles(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(ZIP)
                .body(resource);
}
```

I have tried changing the "produces" type in the config and here under the @ApiOperation to "application/zip" but that doesn't change the example.

Can I remove the example with annotations?

Thank you

Edit: Using Springfox 2.9.2.  It looks like the issue is caused by the version and can be fixed with 3.0.0. If I get a chance to check it I will update.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good solution for responses with `Resource` type:

`@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = byte[].class)`

Also this annotation allows you to specify an example using the `examples` parameter

Comment: Trying to looks up how to correctly use the annotation but can you just throw that line under @ResponseBody and then it will replace the code 200 response?

Comment: I tried that exact line but with "okay" instead of "OK" just to see if it would make the change to the message before working out the example issue.  It doesn't seem to do anything. The current code 200 message and examples are still showing.

Comment: @Werbel Replace your GetMapping with `@GetMapping(path = "/{id}.zip", produces = "application/zip")`

Comment: Adding the "produces" into the GetMapping changes the dropdown box for responses to have application/zip instead of just "/" but the examples are still showing and the code 200 message still isn't changing.  

I did not know that I could add that into GetMapping though. So that's some good info.

Comment: I have a working example, here is the code from there: `@ApiOperation("Download image by ID")` `@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = byte[].class)` `@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "image/*")` `public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(@PathVariable UUID id) {`

Comment: What I have matches up pretty well with what you are showing but still shows a JSON example under the response.  Not sure what else could work.

Comment: Which version of springfox are you using? This code should work on version 3.0.0. Try `@ApiResponses` annotation instead of `@ApiResponse`

Comment: If I move the  response = byte[].class to ApiOperation instead of ApiResponse then the example chages to "string" instead of the JSON I was getting.   This is the first and only thing I have seen that has had an effect on the example.

Comment: I am using springfox 2.9.2.